# How do I search for set items on AH?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was looking at AH today and found a filter for my search.

[image]

As you can see, there there is no option for sets (The green gear or tier, if you are used to Wow).

Is there a way that I can search for sets only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set items are legendary items, so you should find them in that category. There's no way to search only for set items, though.

If you're interested in one specific set item, just put the name down in the search box at the bottom left, that will filter out only this one set item.